# Leer un fichero y que se muestre con salto de linea

Tags: java

Me explico, la idea es un ranking entonces quiero al leer el fichero cada linea me de una linea. osea

```
perico 123
manlo 234
pedro 3
```

No se si con esto vale o no

```
 Ranking {
    private File archivo;

    public void crearArchivo() throws IOException {
        archivo = new File("texto.txt");
        archivo.createNewFile();
    }

    public void escribir(String frase) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
            escribir.write(frase);
            escribir.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al escribir");
        }
    }

    public String leer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String linea;
        String texto = "";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("texto.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            texto += linea;
        }
        fr.close();
        return texto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrega un salto de linea `"\n"` al final de cada linea que ingreses a tu archivo:

```
public void escribir(String frase) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
        escribir.write(frase + "\n");
        escribir.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al escribir");
    }
}


public String leer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String linea;
    String texto = "";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("texto.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
        texto += linea+"\n";
    }
    fr.close();
    return texto;
}
```